# Proving the discontinuity of the function at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a function $f:D\subset\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$,

$${f(x,y)} = \begin{cases}
       \text{$\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{y}}{x^2+y}$} &\quad\text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\\\
       \text{$\large 0$} &\quad\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)\\
     \end{cases}$$

Show that $f(x,y)$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

My approach:

We have,
$$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| = \left |\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{y}}{x^2+y}-0 \right| \\$$
Now I'm unable to find a relation such that $\left |\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{y}}{x^2+y}-0 \right| \geq k*\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Should I use any trigonometric substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you approach the limit for the $x-$axis the limit is one..So the function is not continuous at the origin.

Indeed for $y=0$ and $x \in \Bbb{R}$ we have that $f(x,0)=1$

And also $f(0,y)=0$ on the  $y-$ axis.

Since you want an epsilon proof,assume that $f$ is continuous at the origin.

Then for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall (x,y): \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ then $|f(x,y)|<\frac{1}{2}$

The open delta neighborhood of the origin contains at least one point of the $x-$ axis for instance $(\frac{\delta}{2},0)$ where $f(\frac{\delta }{2},0)=1<\frac{1}{2}$
which is a contadiction.

Comment: Think you mean $x $ axis, points $(x,0) $

Comment: I need an $\epsilon - \delta$ definition if possible.

Comment: For any given $\epsilon$ there are two points (on $x$ and $y$ axes respectively) that are at most $\epsilon$ apart and function has values $0,1$ respectively.

Comment: @SahilSilare i edited my answer.